# Laravel database relations - get all children from more than one parent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have users and books.

User model:

```
public function books() {
   return $this->hasMany('Books');
}
```

I can do the following:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$books = $user->books;
```

Now, I want to get all books from several users with the name Brian.
So what I did is:

```
$users = User::where('name', 'Brian')->get();
$books = $users->books;
```

Of course this does not work because books() is a method of a user and not of a group of users.

How can I can all books from all users named Brian? I could loop through all Brians but that does not seem best practice.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect spot for a `whereHas` call:

Give books a `user` relationship, then simply do:

```
Book::whereHas('user', function($q) {
  $q->whereName('Brian');
})->get();
```